# How can I use rank function to solve this?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, ranking

I have this data:

[image]

and I want to this result:

[image]

So I ve tried this:

```
  SELECT  
      text_area,
      ordered_area,
      RANK () OVER (ORDER BY text_area) ranked_area
       FROM
      (  
      SELECT  '1200 AA' text_area ,1 ordered_area  
       FROM
      DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  '1200 AA'  ,2 
       FROM
      DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  '1200 BB'  ,3 
       FROM
      DUAL 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  '1200 CC'  ,4 
       FROM
      DUAL 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  '1200 CC'  ,5 
       FROM
      DUAL  
      )
```

but it did not solve my problem. How can I solve this issue?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DENSE_RANK not RANK:

```
SELECT  
      text_area,
      ordered_area,
      DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY text_area) ranked_area
       FROM
      (  
      SELECT  '1200 AA' text_area ,1 ordered_area  
       FROM
      DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  '1200 AA'  ,2 
       FROM
      DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  '1200 BB'  ,3 
       FROM
      DUAL 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  '1200 CC'  ,4 
       FROM
      DUAL 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  '1200 CC'  ,5 
       FROM
      DUAL  
      )
```

Comment: By using the partition part you get a rank for each unique value of the column you "partition by".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid "gaps" in your ranking, you should use [`dense_rank`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm) instead of `rank`:

```
DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY text_area) ranked_area
```